# App movil con angular, ionic ... no actualiza los cambios de la web en la app en tiempo real

Tags: android, angular, wordpress, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una app movil con angular ionic compositor y démas ... osea si funciona casi todo, la cosa es que cuando actualizo mi pagina web entro en la app movil pero este no refleja los cambios, tengo que eliminar manualmente la cache de la app para que los cambios se vean reflejados. No se si habra alguna solución, para que cuando haga cambios en mi pagina web pues se reflejen en la app casi automaticamente mientras se navega entre páginas en la app, la página web es admnistrado por wordpress. Les dejo el codigo de la app para ver si podrian ayudarme.

```
//home.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [InAppBrowser],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}  

//home.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private browser: InAppBrowser) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadWebpage();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.loadWebpage();
  }

  private loadWebpage() {

    const browserInstance = this.browser.create('https://example.com/?timestamp=' + Date.now(), '_self', 'location=no,hidenavigationbuttons=true,hideurlbar=true,zoom=no,fullscreen=no');

    browserInstance.on('exit').subscribe(evt => {
   
      App.exitApp();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrías hacer que limpie cache cada cierto tiempo. Por ejemplo cuando cierras la aplicación. 
Lo malo es que tendría que volver a logearse continuamente, yo te recomendaría que lo enfoques de otra manera. Te recomendaría que hicieras llamadas a la API para coger datos y los muestres de forma diferente en la APP. En wordpress tiene una REST API integrada. Busca por google wp_json wordpress